# Meteor and Iron router how integrate Sidebar from html/js template

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have a little problem with Iron router and Meteor, I'll explain what happens :

I have a file named: index.html that contains a toolbar and sidebar,When I use meteor without iron route, index.html is loaded and displayed correctly , sidebar and toolbar works (a click did appear), I have several js files included to manage them.

But when I want route index in one template like :

```
<template name="home">
  <div class="m-scene" id="main">
    <div class="snap-drawers">
      {{> leftSidebar}}
    </div>
    <div class="snap-content z-depth-5" id="content">
      {{> toolBar}}
      <div id="blockui"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

with for example for leftSidebar template :

```
<template name="leftSidebar">
   <div class="snap-drawer snap-drawer-left">
      <div class="drawer-inner">
         <ul>
             <li> 
                 <a href="index.html">
                     <i class="fa fa-home"></i> 
                      <span>Home</span>
                 </a>
             </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
 </template>
```

And toolBar template :

```
<template name="toolBar">
  <div id="toolbar">
     <div class="open-left" id="open-left">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
     </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And associated JavaScript  :

```
  var snapper = new Snap({
      element: document.getElementById('content'),
      hyperextensible: false
  });

  var addEvent = function addEvent(element, eventName, func) {
     if (element) {
        if (element.addEventListener) {
           return element.addEventListener(eventName, func, false);
        } else if (element.attachEvent) {
           return element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, func);
        }
     }
  };

 addEvent(document.getElementById('open-left'), 'click', function(){
    if( snapper.state().state=="left" ){
        snapper.close('left');
        document.getElementById('blockui').style.display="none";
    } else {
        snapper.open('left');
        document.getElementById('blockui').style.display="block";
    }
 });
```

It does not work anymore and and I do not understand why ...

I will summarize because it can be hard to understand, If I did put this html file (without routing) with home and leftSidebar template, all work fine  :

```
<head>
   <title>Asteroid</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{> home}}
</body>
```

But if I use Iron route like that after I delete the index.html file :

```
Router.route('/', {name: 'home'});
```

The home page is visible but the navbar is inaccessible, insensitive to click.
And several display bug appear.

without Iron router, click show leftSideBar :

[image]

with Iron router (clicks does not work anymore):

[image]

Someone can help me ?

thanks

Comment: try to define a main layout  to your router.

Comment: @Mat. I tried but it did not change anything, for you it's normal this behavior ?

Comment: have you tried to wrap your code in a click event on that template??

Comment: I think this is nothing relate it to meteor, is more about when the event handler happening, maybe your event handlers are running before the html is rendered. try to encapsulate your code inside of `Meteor.startup(function(){ //your code here });` and see what happens let me know if worked

Comment: thank you for your answers guys , I wrap my code in a template and I insert the end of a template layout and finally it work